# Node.js app building error "UNMET DEPENDENCY phantomjs-prebuilt@^2.1.4" on Heroku platform

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm, dependency-management

Project is cloned from existing repository and not yet modified:

https://github.com/ebdrup/html2pdf.it

I am looking for piece of information that would help me get through this simple looking yet frustrating warning/error. App cannot successfully run without phantomjs-prebuilt dependency and I am unskilled in Node.js and its project structures.

I have been researching and trying for almost 5 days now. I can manage to run the project locally through Node.js console easily.

The problem seems to be in telling the Heroku where to find the phantomjs-prebuilt file.

I have tried installing the dependency locally in the project directory with:

```
npm install
```

I have tried moving phantomjs binary manually into the bin/

I can run phantomjs on Heroku using:

```
heroku run phantomjs
```

**CMD Output after building on Heroku:**

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  0.10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 0.10.x via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 0.10.48...
remote:        Using default npm version: 2.15.1
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + shrinkwrap)
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── compression@1.4.0
remote:        ├── express@4.11.2
remote:        ├── morgan@1.5.1
remote:        ├── node-uuid@1.4.2
remote:        ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY phantomjs-prebuilt@^2.1.4
remote:        ├── request@2.53.0
remote:        └── slugify-url@1.2.0
remote:
remote:  !     Unmet dependencies don't fail npm install but may cause runtime issues
remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 32.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://h2ptest.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/h2ptest.git
   b278f4b..bce77f9  master -> master
```

**package.json:**

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
  "main": "./lib/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "",
    "morgan": "^1.3.1",
    "node-uuid": "",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "request": "",
    "slugify-url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "",
    "chai": "",
    "sinon": "",
    "sinon-chai": "",
    "underscore": "",
    "mocha-jshint": "",
    "open": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./lib/app.js",
    "test": "_mocha"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
```